# can not get sources from bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

Windows XP, Mercurial 1.6.4

```
hg clone https://demas@bitbucket.org/demas/start.here
destination directory: start.here
requesting all changes
abort: error:
```

But if I use SSH all works fine

```
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/demas/start.here
```

Debug info:

```
hg clone --debug https://demas@bitbucket.org/demas/start.here
using https://bitbucket.org/demas/start.here
http auth: user demas, password not set
sending between command
destination directory: start.here
sending heads command
requesting all changes
sending changegroup command
abort: error:
```

Why? And how I fix it?

Comment: Try updating to a newer Mercurial version, I managed to clone it nicely with 1.7.2.

Comment: I have done it, but nothing changed.  All works fine in one of networks (on the work), but when I trying to clone from home I get this error message. I think it relaited with network settings.

Comment: Hmm... and works if I use http, but not https.

Comment: What does `hg clone --debug <URL>` tell you?

Comment: @demas Have you some http proxy server in between? Can you clone other projects, or without the user name (no demas@ in the url)?

Comment: Please provide the `--traceback` output as well (maybe we should change mercurial to do that by default).

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom configuration to workaround the handling of self-signed certificates:

> Note that per the default settings installed, connect to repositories with self-signed certificates fail with 1.7.3. You need to adjust the default configuration for that case.

**References**

- [CA Certificates in hg on Windows](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CACertificates#Self-signed_certificates)
- [hg import from a https URL fails](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=679808)